# First get list of users from table-1, then compare with current user by specific field from table-2

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What is the procedure to do if I have 2 tables: From table-1 I get all the users I want, and then, after I have the list of user ids, I want to compare each user with current user with a field found on table-2. The first task is easy, I just have an `onDataChange` that populates the users list with their ids. But now that I have this list, how to iterate each user, and compare it with the current user based on a specific field from table-2.

What I currently try is to use a for loop to iterate each user on the list with each having `onDataChange` call to table-2, and then I populate the necessary dataset. But when this for loop ends, this dataset is no longer visible.
I hope what I try to achieve in this post is understandable.

I'll try to demonsrate with tables:

Assuming I get user list from table-1 based on `data1`:

```
table-1
   |
   |_____data1
           |____uid20
           |____uid30
           |____uid44
```

Now I have list of 3 users: `uid20`, `uid30`, `uid44`. Then, I need to compare the list of users, with current user, call it `user1`, from table-1, based on another field (timestamp). What I mean is, after I have list of users, I want to filter these to have a timestamp that's close to the current user, for up to certain amount of time. So in my example, I want to have only users that are within 2 minutes of the current user timestamp.

```
table-2
  |
  |______uid1    
  |        |____timestamp: <some_timestamp>
  |
  |______uid20  
  |        |____timestamp: <some_timestamp>
  |
  |______uid30  
  |        |____timestamp: <some_timestamp>
  |
  |______uid44
           |____timestamp: <some_timestamp>
```

But every time there is something that's out of scope of the new listener, and also it looks like it's not the right procedure. Maybe I first need to save what's found on table-1 locally ? Or, it can be done somehow purely with Firebase calls?

**This is some code:

Getting the current user, is easy:

```
final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
final String userId = user.getUid();
```

So I always have it visible at any scope

Comment: Your example was good to explain the question, but can you tell a bit more about what is `user1` in your example and how are you getting that.

Comment: It's just the string of the user id that's currently uses the app. I added code on how I get it

Comment: I mean what does the part "from table 1, based on another field (timestamp)" in the sentence imply?

Comment: Ok, added to post. What I mean is, that now that I have list of users, I want to filter only users that are within certain time delta of the current user, for example only users whose timestamp is 2 minutes from the current user

Answer (score 1):

First, as I understand, you can use the `startAt` and `endAt` to get a range of the values within two minutes of difference. What I mean is that before getting each value from your table-2 you can just get the values that matches your use case, in this case, values that are 2 minutes of the current timestamp.

For example, in your table 2, I would query like this:

```
ref.orderByChild('timestamp').startAt(yourCurrentTimeStamp).endAt(yourCurrentTimeStamp+120000);
```

where 120000 is **2 seconds** in miliseconds

and then when looping through this elements I would use getKey to get each key of the values filtered by this query, so I would get only the users with 2 minutes of difference, and then compare them with the first for loop you did in order to see if they match.

to compare 2 users ID you can use equals, since it's a String:

```
if(snapshotUserTable1.getKey().equals(snapshotUserTable2.getKey())){
/...
}
```